# Displaying Math.random() in h1 tag jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I'm trying to do is display the math.random number in the h1 tag by using jQuery and for some reason it's not working I'm not sure whats going wrong. For some reason when I take out the function it works but why is that?

**HTML**

```
<h1></h1>
```

**jQuery**

```
function time(){
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random());
  $('h1').text(number);
}
```

Comment: You have to call the function. Did you call the `time()` function?

Comment: What specifically does "not working" mean?

Comment: Make sure that JQuery is referenced prior to the script code and that the function you've written is executed after the HTML has finished loading (put your function and its call inside of a document.ready event handler). And, you need to actually call your function.

Comment: Also note that `Math.floor(Math.random())` is rather pointless, as it will always equal `0`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you that worked! Always thought document.ready was worthless but I guess I know not anymore.

Comment: Ask yourself "How can `$('h1')` locate the correct HTML element if that element hasn't been read into memory yet?" That is why the all important `document.ready()` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using $ which is a jquery selector in a form that doesnot know about JQuery .
So please use this code instead :

```
function Thetime(){
         $(document).ready(function() {
              var number = Math.floor(Math.random());
              $('h1').text(number);
        });
    }
```

Hope this will solve your problem .
a side note : you are flooring the generated number , that might always lead to ZERO , So you can also only use Math.random() instead of Math.floor(Math.random());

Thanks

Comment: Ya it turned out just needed to add a $(document).ready(function(){}); and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the `time()` function to make it perform its operations.

Here is your code running:

```js
function time(){
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random());
  $('h1').text(number);
}

// call your function to run it
time();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```

**NOTE:** You may notice that your number is always `0`. This is because `Math.random()` creates a float between `0` and `1` (eg: `0.22378`). Likewise, `Math.floor()` will take any floating point number and round it down to the nearest integer. So a random number like `0.22378` will always be floored to `0`. If you want to randomize between a range of whole numbers you need to multiply your random number by your maximum *then* floor the result.

```
var max = 30;
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
```

Comment: Thank you I already knew that but I was just testing it out, thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

@ScottMarcus answered the question, all I had to do was add a document.ready to the function. Just going to leave this up for any new beginning coders.